# How do I create a forest of graphs in a graph which is disconnected in Scala?

Tags: scala, graph

Assume that the graph looks like:

```
class DiGraph[T] (val edges: LinkedHashMap[T, LinkedHashSet[T]])
```

The graph is disconnected and has many roots.

Of course the sources that are roots can be found by identifying those sources that are not found in the values (the sets). Then the paths connected to each source can be traced.

What is the best way to find the forest of graphs?